# MailTo for Group Email

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4

Currently, I have this code:

```
<a href="mailto:Support Team(sample143@example.com)"><img src="~/Images/4.jpg" width="30" /></a><span class="text">Developers</span>
```

The Support Team is the display name of the Email Address but the Email Address is `sample143@example.com`. When I try this code, this will display in my outlook `Support Team(sample143@example.com)` and I still need to check names before I could send the email. What I wanted to do is when I click the mailto link, Support Team will automatically display in my outlook and no need for me to check names.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too sure whether you can link multiple emails in this way, however when you input the group email, the email should be sent to all recipients in that group. So if you have your group correctly configured, there's no need to worry about the recipients. (I assume that sample143@example.com is your group email for the support team.)
Just use:

```
<a href="mailto:sample143@example.com"><img src="~/Images/4.jpg" width="30" /></a><span class="text">Developers</span>
```

and the whole support team will get your message. If you want your message sent to only several members of the support team, just use their individual emails seperated by a semi colon.

Answer (score 1):

if you need to  show namewith e-mail address

use  `<a href="mailto: Support Team<sample143@example.com>"><`

if you want show e-mail only,

use `<a href="mailto: sample143@example.com"><`